# Is there a way to select the color of an Excel cell and have it run a specific action automatically?

Tags: excel

I am building a spreadsheet to track grant spending through the year. I have every column set up with a color and the amount of money we have been allotted for that category. The left side is for adding the person's name who worked the operation, the date, time, # of hours, and the pay rate for that person. I would like to be able to color code the person's name or one of the entries in Columns A thru E...

The magical thing I want it to do is based on the color selected, automatically calculate the product of the # of hours x Pay Rate, and input that number into the corresponding column to the right.

Example:
Joe Smith worked DDT 09/01/2023 from 1000-1200. That would be 2 hours in the # of hours spot and he gets paid $50 per hour which goes in Column E. I would like to be able to select the light blue color for Joe's row and have it automatically input the $100 product into the corresponding row in Column H.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the spreadsheet]

I really don't know how this is possible...

Comment: I would recommend that you input the text and the cell changes color to blue. That is the way that excel does things.